# filezilla showing error while connecting to FTP server

Tags: ftp, filezilla

When I tried to connect to an FTP server using **filezilla** it was showing an error.

```
*connection attempt failed with "10051".
Could not connect to server.*
```

What error is this and how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [What Are the Common Causes of Socket Error 10051?](http://www.wisegeek.com/what-are-the-common-causes-of-socket-error-10051.htm)

> A socket error, such as socket error 10051, occurs whenever one computer attempts to connect to another network or server. Error 10051 happens because the other network is unreachable, usually because there is a problem with the router or modem on the computer attempting the connection.

Comment: So basically the internet connection is a problem?

Comment: Yes, somehow filezilla cannot reach the server.

Comment: The more common name for this error is "no route to host".